# In Multitenant application,How we are Handle Schema once schema created in database and How can change the tables properties

Tags: entity-framework

I have developing a  small multitenant application using Seperate Schema Shared Database  approach? How to Handle the Seperate Schema after dynamically created the runtime schema , Steps: Once Tenant Enter into Registration page ,the registered tenant has runtime schema should be allocated and Created  . I have created this by using some discussion and post seen  in the stack overflow  .https://entityframework.codeplex.com/discussions/462765

Now am struggling in that

What is the syntax for getting the Schema name in Entity framework 
 i have dynamically created schema in database but i want to show the particular schema (table ) data into webpage in list or grid ,  what is the syntax for handling schema mapping in ef
normally we use
 using (databasecontext obj = new databasecontext)  by using instance we get the tables in the context but how we get the schema name and show the particular tenant tables in list or gridview .

2) once dynamically created the schema , If i want to add or delete some column for particular tenant table how can i do this without affecting another tenant

3)how migration solve this issue ? orelse is there anyother way to achieve this  if anyone know please help me as soon as possible